# Recursive MySql Trigger not working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to setup a MySql trigger to run after data is inserted/updated in ODBC

My trigger is below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `myTrigger`
AFTER INSERT ON `testTable` FOR EACH ROW UPDATE `testTable` SET `Field One` = CONCAT(`Field One`, ' - Trigger');
```

My trigger statement runs in MySql workbench ok but when I connect to `testTable` from a Microsoft Access database and then try and insert a row I get one of these:

[image: Access Error]

To make things even more interesting, when I try to run the following:

```
INSERT INTO `testTable` (`Field One`, `Field Two`, `Field Three`, `Field Four`, `Field Five`) VALUES ('x', 'xx', 'xxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxxx')
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR 1442: Can't update table 'testtable' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

The full trigger code from my `Triggers` tab in workbench is below:

```
-- Trigger DDL Statements
DELIMITER $$

USE `FooBar`$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`JMK`@`%`
TRIGGER `myTrigger`
AFTER INSERT ON `testtable`
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE `testTable` SET `Field One` = CONCAT(`Field One`, ' - Trigger')$$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the query to add the trigger was syntactically correct and was executed, it does not mean that the trigger function is valid.

Your trigger triggers itself. This is from the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html):

> - Stored functions cannot be used recursively.
> - Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

Comment: Aaah, so my Update trigger triggers an Update and this goes around in a loop?

Comment: @JMK, Yes. That's what's happening.

Comment: OK, is there way to create a trigger that runs after an insert or update but doesn't fall into this trap?

Comment: @JMK, Usually, triggers are used to update a different table. I would start another question, explain what you're trying to do, provide as many details as you can, and find out what the recommended solutions are. Perhaps the solution isn't a trigger at all.